# iOS | Swift | Image view in scrollview going out of sight when zoomed

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I have below simple view hierarchy:
view
--- scrollView
--- scrollContentView
--- imageView
Issue being faced is that image is zooming properly both in horizontal and vertical direction and can easily pan it but if I scroll image up or down then the zoomed image goes completely out of sight. How can this be prevented ? I want the image to remain in view and should not go completely out of sight.
Below code:

```
    private var scrollView = UIScrollView()
    private let scrollContentView = UIView()
    private let imageView = UIImageView()
    
    private lazy var scrollContentViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
            return scrollContentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor)
        }()
    private lazy var scrollContentViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
            return scrollContentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor)
        }()
    private lazy var scrollContentViewLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
            return scrollContentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor)
        }()
    private lazy var scrollContentViewTrailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
            return scrollContentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor)
        }()
    private lazy var scrollContentViewWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
            return scrollContentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor, priority: .defaultLow)
        }()
    private lazy var scrollContentViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
            return scrollContentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor, priority: .defaultHigh)
        }()

view.addSubview(scrollView)
scrollView.addSubview(scrollContentView)
scrollContentView.addSubview(imageView)


scrollView.delegate = self
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollContentViewTopConstraint,
            scrollContentViewBottomConstraint,
            scrollContentViewLeadingConstraint,
            scrollContentViewTrailingConstraint,
            scrollContentViewWidthConstraint,
            scrollContentViewHeightConstraint
        ])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollContentView.topAnchor),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollContentView.bottomAnchor),
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollContentView.leadingAnchor),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollContentView.trailingAnchor)
        ])

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return scrollContentView
    }
```

Comment: Are you using some extension to allow adding `, priority: .defaultLow` to your constraint? Maybe that's messing things up. And, I don't know why you would change those priorities anyway. Plus, you're not showing where you are loading an image. If I run your code (without the `priority` settings), it seems to work fine.

Comment: @DonMag, image is being set from assets and not downloaded from any network resource. Are you able to move image completely out of sight in vertical direction  or is it still remains visible ? When we pan in horizontal direction then majority of image portion remains visible and it do not go out of sight completely. I want to achieve same behaviour in vertical direction.

Comment: The image does not scroll out of view in either direction. Are you maybe using a "wide" image, with the imageView's content mode set to Aspect Fit?

Comment: Yes @DonMag, the content mode is AspectFit. Image is a wide image.

Comment: OK - so, you have an image view as a subview of your `scrollContentView`, and you want to zoom the `scrollContentView` but only to the extent of the image? It sounds like you need this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63469412/6257435

Comment: @DonMag, Your above link helped a lot and solved my issue. Thanks