# Panning an ImageView inside a ScrollView when contentMode is AspectFill

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have an ImageView inside a ScrollView and a button to toggle the contentMode between .scaleAspectFit and .scaleAspectFill. I've added the ability to zoom and pan but it only works when the contentMode is .scaleAspectFit.

I would like to be able to pan the image to see the parts of the image not showing when in .scaleAspectFill as the image takes up the entire scrollView as desired.

I haven't been able to find anything on how to do this, any help or hint would be very much appreciated.

Comment: See if this answer does what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63469412/6257435

Answer (score 0):

As of my understanding zoom and pan inside UIScrollView will not work with .scaleAspectFill. It's a chicken and egg problem: somehow the actual size of the image has to be defined for the scrollview to know it's content size.

Instead of trying to toggle `contentMode` you should programmatically change to different zoom levels, e.g. zoom to fill available space vs. zoom out to see full image.