# UIScrollView - when is contentSize set

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a UIViewController and it's view hierarchy looks like this:

- `UIView`

  - `UIScrollView`

    - `UIImageView`

I have code that positions the image view in the middle of the scroll view's frame, like so:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self recenterContent:scrollView];
}

- (void)recenterContent:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    //this centers the content when it is smaller than the scrollView's bounds
    CGFloat offsetX = MAX((scrollView.bounds.size.width - scrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5, 0.0);
    CGFloat offsetY = MAX((scrollView.bounds.size.height - scrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5, 0.0);
    
    self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(offsetY, offsetX, 0.f, 0.f);
}
```

This works fine when zooming the content, but when the view controller first loads it does not center. This is because the `scrollView.contentSize` is always `0`. So my question is - when should I call this method after the scrollView.contentSize is set? When does that get set?

I have tried in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, and the bounds of the scroll view is set then, but not the content size. Is there some method that I can use where the scroll view will be guaranteed to have the content size set?

Or is there a better way to keep the image centered when it is smaller than the scroll view? What I am trying to accomplish is to have it so the image view is not at the top of the scroll view and what I am using works, except when the scroll view's content size is not set. But if there is a better way of doing this without having to adjust the `contentInset`, I would be fine with that too.

---

## Update

Here is what I have currently.

[image]

It is almost working, but no matter what I try, I cannot get it to look correct when the view loads. The way it works now is that it starts out off-center because when it calls the `recenterContent` method, before the view is displayed the content size of the scroll view is CGSizeZero, so the calculations are wrong. But if I try to recenter the content after the view has been displayed, then there is a visible delay before it gets centered.

I am just confused as to when the contentSize of the scroll view is set if I am using AutoLayout constraints to specify the size.

Here is my code. Can anyone see anything wrong with it?

```
@interface MyImageViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL needsZoomScale;

@end

@implementation MyImageViewController

- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
    
    self.needsZoomScale = YES;
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        [self.scrollView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leadingAnchor],
        [self.scrollView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor],
        [self.scrollView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.trailingAnchor],
        [self.scrollView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor],
        
        [self.imageView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor],
        [self.imageView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor],
        [self.imageView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor],
        [self.imageView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor]
    ]];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapZoom:)];
    doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGesture];
}

- (CGRect)zoomRectForScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withScale:(CGFloat)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center {
    CGRect zoomRect;
    
    //the zoom rect is in the content view's coordinates. At a zoom scale of 1.0, the zoom rect would be the size
    //of the scroll view's bounds. As the zoom scale decreases, so more content is visible, the size of the rect
    //grows.
    zoomRect.size.width = scrollView.frame.size.width / scale;
    zoomRect.size.height = scrollView.frame.size.height / scale;
    
    //choose an origin so as to get the right center
    zoomRect.origin.x = center.x - (zoomRect.size.width / 2.0);
    zoomRect.origin.y = center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);
    
    return zoomRect;
}

- (void)doubleTapZoom:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    UIView *tappedView = sender.view;
    CGPoint tappedPoint = [sender locationInView:tappedView];
    
    if (tappedPoint.x <= 0) {
        tappedPoint.x = 1;
    }
    
    if (tappedPoint.y <= 0) {
        tappedPoint.y = 1;
    }
    
    if (tappedPoint.x >= tappedView.bounds.size.width) {
        tappedPoint.x = tappedView.bounds.size.width - 1;
    }
    
    if (tappedPoint.y >= tappedView.bounds.size.height) {
        tappedPoint.y = tappedView.bounds.size.height - 1;
    }

    CGFloat zoomScale;
    if (self.scrollView.zoomScale < 1) {
        zoomScale = 1;
    } else if (self.scrollView.zoomScale < self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale) {
        zoomScale = self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale;
    } else {
        zoomScale = self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale;
    }
    
    CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScrollView:self.scrollView withScale:zoomScale withCenter:tappedPoint];
    
    [self.scrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
}

- (UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (!self->_scrollView) {
        self->_scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
        self->_scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self->_scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.1f;
        self->_scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0f;
        self->_scrollView.bounces = YES;
        self->_scrollView.bouncesZoom = YES;
        self->_scrollView.delegate = self;
        self->_scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    return self->_scrollView;
}

- (UIImageView *)imageView {
    if (!self->_imageView) {
        self->_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        self->_imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self->_imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self->_imageView;
}

- (UIImage *)image {
    return self.imageView.image;
}

- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image {
    self.imageView.image = image;
    self.needsZoomScale = YES;
    [self updateZoomScale];
}

- (void)updateZoomScale {
    if (self.needsZoomScale && self.image) {
        CGSize size = self.view.bounds.size;
        
        if (size.width == 0.0f || size.height == 0.0f) {
            return;
        }
            
        UIImage *image = self.image;
        CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width * image.scale, image.size.height * image.scale);
        if (imageSize.width > 0 && imageSize.height > 0) {
            CGFloat widthScale = size.width / imageSize.width;
            CGFloat heightScale = size.height / imageSize.height;
            CGFloat minScale = MIN(widthScale, heightScale);
                
            self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale;
            self.scrollView.zoomScale = minScale;
            self.needsZoomScale = NO;
        }
    }
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    [self updateZoomScale];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self recenterContent:self.scrollView];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self recenterContent:self.scrollView];
}

#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return self.imageView;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self recenterContent:scrollView];
}

- (void)recenterContent:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    //this centers the content when it is smaller than the scrollView's bounds
    CGFloat offsetX = MAX((scrollView.bounds.size.width - scrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5, 0.0);
    CGFloat offsetY = MAX((scrollView.bounds.size.height - scrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5, 0.0);
    
    self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(offsetY, offsetX, 0.f, 0.f);
}

@end
```

Comment: See if this answer does what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63469412/6257435

Comment: @DonMag Thanks so much. I will look at this and see. It looks like a really great example.

Comment: @DonMag I have looked at your example and in terms of the centering code, they are similar. Everything is working for me except centering the image before the view loads. The way it is acting right now is that it starts out off-center because the contentSize is zero before the view is displayed, or so it seems. I honestly do not know when the scrollView.contentSize is set for layouts using AutoLayout. But if I try to do the centering in viewDidAppear, then it is too late and there is a jump. I added an update to my question with my code. Do you see anything wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a `UIImageView` has an intrinsic content size of `0,0` -- so your code is initially putting the a `0x0` image view at the center of the scroll view.

I've made a few changes to the code you posted... see comments (I "wrapped" the changes in

```
// ---------------------------------
```

comment lines:

```
@interface MyImageViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
@end

@interface MyImageViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL needsZoomScale;

@end

@implementation MyImageViewController

- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];

    self.needsZoomScale = YES;
    
    // ---------------------------------
    //  respect safe area
    UILayoutGuide *g = [self.view safeAreaLayoutGuide];
    //  saves on a little typing
    UILayoutGuide *sg = [self.scrollView contentLayoutGuide];
    // ---------------------------------

    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        [self.scrollView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor],
        [self.scrollView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor],
        [self.scrollView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor],
        [self.scrollView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.bottomAnchor],
        
        [self.imageView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:sg.leadingAnchor],
        [self.imageView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:sg.topAnchor],
        [self.imageView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:sg.trailingAnchor],
        [self.imageView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:sg.bottomAnchor]
    ]];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapZoom:)];
    doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGesture];
}

- (CGRect)zoomRectForScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withScale:(CGFloat)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center {
    CGRect zoomRect;
    
    //the zoom rect is in the content view's coordinates. At a zoom scale of 1.0, the zoom rect would be the size
    //of the scroll view's bounds. As the zoom scale decreases, so more content is visible, the size of the rect
    //grows.
    zoomRect.size.width = scrollView.frame.size.width / scale;
    zoomRect.size.height = scrollView.frame.size.height / scale;
    
    //choose an origin so as to get the right center
    zoomRect.origin.x = center.x - (zoomRect.size.width / 2.0);
    zoomRect.origin.y = center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);
    
    return zoomRect;
}

- (void)doubleTapZoom:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    UIView *tappedView = sender.view;
    CGPoint tappedPoint = [sender locationInView:tappedView];
    
    if (tappedPoint.x <= 0) {
        tappedPoint.x = 1;
    }
    
    if (tappedPoint.y <= 0) {
        tappedPoint.y = 1;
    }
    
    if (tappedPoint.x >= tappedView.bounds.size.width) {
        tappedPoint.x = tappedView.bounds.size.width - 1;
    }
    
    if (tappedPoint.y >= tappedView.bounds.size.height) {
        tappedPoint.y = tappedView.bounds.size.height - 1;
    }
    
    CGFloat zoomScale;
    if (self.scrollView.zoomScale < 1) {
        zoomScale = 1;
    } else if (self.scrollView.zoomScale < self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale) {
        zoomScale = self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale;
    } else {
        zoomScale = self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale;
    }
    
    CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScrollView:self.scrollView withScale:zoomScale withCenter:tappedPoint];
    
    [self.scrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
}

- (UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (!self->_scrollView) {
        self->_scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
        self->_scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self->_scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.1f;
        self->_scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0f;
        self->_scrollView.bounces = YES;
        self->_scrollView.bouncesZoom = YES;
        self->_scrollView.delegate = self;
        self->_scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    return self->_scrollView;
}

- (UIImageView *)imageView {
    if (!self->_imageView) {
        self->_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        self->_imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self->_imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self->_imageView;
}

- (UIImage *)image {
    return self.imageView.image;
}

- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image {
    self.imageView.image = image;
    
    // ---------------------------------
    //  set the frame here
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    
    // ---------------------------------
    //  not needed ... unless maybe changing the image while view is showing?
    //self.needsZoomScale = YES;
    //[self updateZoomScale];
}

- (void)updateZoomScale {
    if (self.needsZoomScale && self.image) {
        CGSize size = self.view.bounds.size;
        
        if (size.width == 0.0f || size.height == 0.0f) {
            return;
        }
        
        UIImage *image = self.image;
        CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width * image.scale, image.size.height * image.scale);
        if (imageSize.width > 0 && imageSize.height > 0) {
            CGFloat widthScale = size.width / imageSize.width;
            CGFloat heightScale = size.height / imageSize.height;
            CGFloat minScale = MIN(widthScale, heightScale);
            
            self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale;
            self.scrollView.zoomScale = minScale;
            self.needsZoomScale = NO;
        }
    }
}

// ---------------------------------
//  Don't need this
//- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
//  [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
//  [self updateZoomScale];
//}
// ---------------------------------

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    // ---------------------------------
    //  update zoom scale here
    [self updateZoomScale];
    // ---------------------------------
    
    [self recenterContent:self.scrollView];
}

// ---------------------------------
//  Don't need this
//- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
//  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
//  [self recenterContent:self.scrollView];
//}
// ---------------------------------

#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return self.imageView;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self recenterContent:scrollView];
}

- (void)recenterContent:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    //this centers the content when it is smaller than the scrollView's bounds
    CGFloat offsetX = MAX((scrollView.bounds.size.width - scrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5, 0.0);
    CGFloat offsetY = MAX((scrollView.bounds.size.height - scrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5, 0.0);
    
    self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(offsetY, offsetX, 0.f, 0.f);
}

@end
```

and here's how I call it:

```
MyImageViewController *vc = [MyImageViewController new];

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bkg"];
if (nil == img) {
    NSLog(@"Could not load image!!!!");
    return;
}
[vc setImage:img];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked. I was under the impression that an image view would get the intrinsic content size of the image assigned to it, but I guess not? So basically, every time I set an image on an image view, I should always set the width and height. Is that a correct takeaway? Thank you so much for your help with this issue and my previous issues. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: It *will* get the intrinsic size based on the `.image` ... which is why the code worked **after** zooming it for the first time. It just wasn't getting set yet. You could also replace the `.frame = ...` line with `[self.imageView sizeToFit];` and it should accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Okay, that's great to know. Thank you again.