# UIScrollView: Limit panning to edges of image bounds

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I'm working on an app that lets a user input an image and pan/zoom around it with a UIScrollView.

I have everything working, but when zoomed in the app lets the user pan way above the bounds of the image, as it's using AspectFit.

How would I stop the user from panning past the bounds of the image?

Thanks.

Comment: The limits of the scroll view are defined by the scroll view’s content size. You would have to calculate the new content size of the view to match the size of the image after any transformation was done to it.

Comment: Take a look at this answer and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63469412/6257435

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.